# Multiple Submit from Drop downs in a single Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 setup with two Dropdowns that via Javascript automatically submits when a value is selected.
They are currently inside the same form, so i would like to have them submit to different Actions on my Backend

View:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "BrugerSession"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Emails)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ValgtEmail, Model.Emails, "Vælg Email")
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Printere)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ValgtPrinter, Model.Printere)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ValgtEmail").change(function () {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ValgtPrinter").change(function () {
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

The trick here is, that i am using [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) to support multiple submit-targets in the Backend.

Why main Question is: Can the Javascript Trigger method submit the data in the propper way, so it will works with the Solution from the above link?

I tried looking into the http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ Documentation and there is support for additional parameters. But i do know how to format my Javascript to achieve what I need.

**Update:**

I never managed to get this working. Instead i surrounded each Select with its own form.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will help you. You can use JQuery AJAX.

**First drop down**

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/Action1',
        data: { parm1:parm1 },
        success: function () {
         // Success function
        },
        error: function () {
         // Error message
        }
    });
});
```

**Second drop down**

```
$("#dropdown2").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ControllerName/Action2',
        data: { parm1:parm1 },
        success: function () {
         // Success function
        },
        error: function () {
         // Error message
        }
    });
});
```